# User profile page is inaccessible

Tags: bug, profile-page

I was lurking around on Meta when I saw that [this user (Makoto)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) had answered a question, and decided to check out their profile page, however, it takes an abnormally long time to load (in fact, it did not load at all, as of writing this post, 1:20 pm UTC, 16 December 2021).

I thought this is a bug that should be reported, and therefore, decided to pose a question asking if this issue has already been noticed.

Comment: Opened for me instantly...

Comment: Do you mean switching for the main profile from the meta one? Because that indeed doesn't load up for me as well...

Comment: @Tomerikoo other user profiles load fast for me (even yours did) but this one simply isn't.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it clear that you mean the main site profile. It is confusing as the linked one is the meta which opens fine...

Comment: I get a server error on the main and meta profile after ~30 seconds of loading.

Comment: For one moment even my own profile didn't load with this *"Oops! Something went wrong!"* message. But now both mine and Makoto's profiles load instantly...

Comment: Can confirm your observations. I was seeing the "Oops! Something went wrong!" page when trying to load profiles on the main site (entirely unrelated to looking at Makoto's). All seems to be working now, though, so just a transient hiccup.

Comment: "I thought this is a bug that should be reported"  That's an assumption, it might also be a server issue or the side effect of maintenance being performed. I make a different assumption - that monitoring is in place and it's just a matter of waiting for the problem to be resolved.