# The “Answers” card on the Activity page does not show any titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, activity-tab

As of the time of posting this, this is how [the “Answers” section in my Activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1444609/i-wrestled-a-bear-once) looks on Chrome (not logged in) and Firefox (logged in):

[image: Screenshot of the Answers and Questions sections of the Activity page. The titles of Answers are not shown at all.]

None of the tabs (Votes, Activity, Newest) in the Answers card are rendering properly.

Someone [posted an issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414797/user-profile-page-is-inaccessible) earlier about their profile not loading at all. Could this be related? Or Maybe it's related to the Winter Bash Hats? I did just put on a hat.

This appears to be an issue on all Stack Exchange sites. Although my network profile is fine.

Comment: Report bugs [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page). Can confirm I see the same on Firefox.

Comment: Can reproduce in multiple browsers. These kinds of bugs are frustrating. I wish the developers would stop breaking things that used to work just fine and did not need changing. :-\

Comment: Imagine if they used a proper migration process with a development, testing and production environment instead of pushing untested "fixes" straight out, @CodyGray ! Most of the stupid mistakes we'd never see and the Devs wouldn't look so foolish! :)

Comment: I gave up on that hope *long* ago, @Larnu. Now I just wish they'd stop what they're doing altogether. Especially when the "improvements" are the opposite.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not *sure* that's the right place for it.  The responsive activity page was launched on all sites on the 7th.  This *may* be more related to [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/902710) where the staff *does* ask that new questions be open for each bug report.  That said, it could certainly be a regression that was caused while they were working on other bug fixes in Responsive Activity.

Comment: Possibly, @NotTheDr01ds . I don't know if the bug is related to ongoing "fixes" to the Activity page, which is still being changed, or that announcement (which really should be [[meta-tag:featured]]).

Comment: This bug was introduced by a change in our model unrelated to the recent Activity page changes. We're on it!

Comment: Same report on Meta.SE: [No question titles for user's answers in the Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374104/818993)

Comment: Now also reported here: [New responsive Activity page](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/374107/289905).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed

> answer titles blank?
> sorry for the regression
> back to normal now